# Warum ist religiöses Glauben gleich dem Wort "Glauben" (Unsicherheit)?

Tags: etymology

Ich selbst bin Atheist und finde diese Wortwahl passend, aber verstehe sie im historischen Kontext nicht.

Warum sagt man "ich *glaube*, dass es morgen regnet", wenn man eine gewisse Unsicherheit ausdrücken will, aber "ich *glaube* an Gott", wenn man (als Theist) eine sichere Aussage machen will?

War es nicht eher immer so, dass religiöses Glauben der (als sicher geltende) Standard  der Bevölkerung ist, den man nicht anzweifeln darf?

Wie hat sich — unter diesem Umstand – die Sprache so entwickelt, dass der Ausdruck der Religiösität gleich dem Ausdruck der Unsicherheit ist?

Im englischen ist es ähnlich: "I believe it will rain tomorrow", aber auch: "I believe in my religion".

Comment: ...und auf Spanisch (creo que va a llover *und* creer en dios), und auf Französisch (je crois qu'il pleuvra *und* croire en dieu), usw. Ich weiß im Deutschen nicht, wie es funktioniert. In meiner Muttersprache kommt mir diese Übereinstimmung vor, als ob man freiwilig auf den Verstand in beiden Fällen verzichten würde.

Comment: Man sagt auch, man glaube jemandem, das ist also nicht auf einen religiösen Kontext beschränkt.

Comment: Glauben: *eher gefühlsmäßig; von etwas nicht objektiv Bewiesenem*. Und Wiktionary besagt, *gauben* habe eine gemeinsame Adkejtivwurzel mit dem Englischen *believe*, und zwar *ga-lauba*.

Comment: "Er verachtet die Adepten der Tradition, die »zuerst glauben, daß andere wissen, was sie nicht wissen; und nachher, daß sie selbst wissen, was sie nicht wissen." (Adorno über Bacon, Dialektik d. Aufklärung).

Comment: Man sagt ja auch "glauben heißt: nicht wissen", daher ist "Ich glaube an Gott" doch genau das gleiche. Man glaubt an ihn, man weiß es aber nicht.

Comment: @Sentry: Es ist nicht das selbe. Ich weiß auch nicht ob ich 99 Jahre alt werde - dennoch glaube ich es nicht; einerseits. Ich kann aber andererseits doch glauben, dass ich mindestens 55 werde. Das ist aber ein leidenschaftsloses für-wahrscheinlich-halten. Das religiöse Glauben ist da anders, von der Zugabe der Frömmigkeit bis zum Furor des missionarischen Eifers. Es gibt aber zweifelsohne Gemeinsamkeiten.

Comment: "Glauben" also means "believe".

Answer (score 18):

#### Etymologie

Wenn man sich die Etymologie von [*glauben*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=glauben) anschaut, kann man sehen, dass es sich hier um ein sehr altes Wort handelt, das schon im Althochdeutschen seit dem 8. Jahrhundert belegt ist (**gilouben**).

Schon immer kam ihm die Bedeutung eines Wissens aus innerer Überzeugung aber ohne beweisbare äußere Belege bei. Daher wundert nicht, dass *glauben* immer auch eng mit Religion und dem Glauben an einen Gott verknüpft war.

#### Präfigierung von „lieb“

Interessant ist, dass es sich offenbar um eine Präfigierung des Wortes *lieb* (ahd. **liob**) mit *ge-* handelt, also ursprünglich und noch heute im Sinne eines lieb (angenehm, wertvoll) gewonnenen Gedankens verstanden wurde.

Auch im Englischen findet sich derselbe Wortstamm mit der gleichen Bedeutung in **love** und **believe**, mit dem Unterschied, dass schon im Altenglischen neben *ge-* auch ein anderes Präfix, nämlich *be-* gebildet wurde (**belȳfan**).

#### Heutige Bedeutung

In der heutigen Nebenbedeutung des Beispiels *ich glaube, dass* steckt immer noch die Bedeutung eines „lieb gewonnenen Gedankens, der nicht weiter belegt werden kann“.

Eine ungewisse Sache wird deshalb häufig mit *glauben* ausgedrückt *(ich glaube nicht, dass)*, und man unterscheidet sie genau dadurch von der Aussage *ich weiß, dass*.

Kaum verwunderlich ist auch, dass in der wissenschaftlich geprägten Gegenwartskultur einer „geglaubten“ Sache eine geringere Bedeutung beigemessen wird.

Das ist aber nicht generell so, denn es gibt auch heute Menschen, denen – ganz außerhalb einer religiösen Bedeutung – der Glaube an eine Sache wichtiger ist als bewiesene Fakten.

Answer (score 8):

Die Wendung

> Ich glaube, dass es morgen regnen wird.

hat ursprünglich keine Unsicherheit ausgedrückt. Der Sprecher hat damit seine eigene Sicherheit ausgedrückt. Im gleichen Maß wurde auch „religiös“ geglaubt:

> Ich glaube an Gott.

In manchen Ländern, die die europäische Aufklärung *nicht* durchgemacht haben, gibt es auch immer noch keinen Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Verwendungen.

Erst die europäische Aufklärung hat in modernen Zeiten dazu geführt, einen Unterschied zwischen Denken, Fühlen und Glauben zu sehen. Außerdem hat sie die Überlegenheit des Denkens propagiert. In Descartes' „Cogito ergo sum“-Textstelle wird das Denken als unerschütterliche Gewissheit gesehen, während Glauben und Fühlen (Descartes spricht Gott, Himmel und Körper) bezweifelt werden können.

In Folge dieser Überlegenheit des Denkens in der europäischen Weltauffassung wird die Wendung

> Ich glaube, dass es morgen regnen wird.

zum Eingeständnis, dass man sich nicht sicher ist, dass es morgen regnen wird, weil es eben kein Denken, sondern „nur“ Glauben ist.

Demhingegen wird die Wendung

> Ich glaube an Gott.

zu einer Kampfansage gegen das universale Denken.

Comment: Das passt nicht ganz. Siehe meiner Antwort und die Etymologie hier: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=glauben An Gott glauben =  Gott-Vertrauen, Etwas für wahr halten ist nicht von etwas überzeugt sein. Gott lieb halten ist nicht das gleiche wie von Gott überzeugt sein.

Comment: @DisplayName Die Entwicklung der Wortbedeutung hin zu einer kritischen Verwendung hat schon vor der Aufklärung und sogar schon vor der Scholastik begonnen. Zumindest Pfeiffers Ethymologie zufolge kann ich nicht erkennen, dass `glauben` auch schon im Althochdeutschen eine Konnotation von „schlechter/weniger als wissen/denken“ hatte.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ich glaube (vertraue) dir (mal). (ich kann es eh nicht nachprüfen)
2. Ich glaube du hast recht. (siehe 1.)
3. Ich glaube an GOTT. (siehe 1.) (Man kann es ja nicht nachprüfen.)

Glauben bedeutet nicht Wissen. Bzw. nicht wissenschaftlich nachprüfbar oder wiederholbar. Bzw. noch nicht reproduziert oder verifiziert. Wenn man etwas glaubt, vertraut man darauf, dass, in diesem Fall die Kirche und alle anderen Gläubigen, wissen was sie tun und das die heiligen Texte stimmen.

Man kann ja nicht wirklich direkt nachprüfen, wer diese geschrieben hat und warum und woher das alles kommt.

Ein Synonym für glauben ist sich ziemlich sicher zu sein.

Ich glaube morgen regnet es. Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher morgen regnet es. Garantiert regnet es morgen, da bin ich mir ziemlich sicher.

Siehe auch die Etymologie von hier: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=glauben

> glauben Vb. ‘**annehmen**, **vermuten**, für wahr halten, eine religiöse
>   Überzeugung haben’, ahd. gilouben (8. Jh.), mhd. g(e)louben, asächs.
>   gilōҍian, mnd. gelȫven, mnl. ghelōven, nl. geloven, aengl. gelēfan,
>   gelīefan, (mit anderem Präfix) belȳfan, belēfan, engl. to believe,
>   got. galaubjan ist ein Präfixverb mit Ablaut zu dem unter lieb (s. d.)
>   behandelten Adjektiv im Sinne von ‘**lieb halten**, lieb nennen’. Wohl
>   bereits in vorchristlicher Zeit bezieht sich das Verb auf das
>   vertrauensvolle Verhältnis zwischen Mensch und heidnischem Gott (vgl.
>   Wissmann Älteste Postverbalia, 1938, 40), so daß es in der got.,
>   angelsächs. und ahd. Missionssprache für griech. pisté͞uein
>   (πιστεύειν) bzw. lat. crēdere ‘(ver)trauen, glauben, für wahr halten’
>   eintreten und das Verhältnis des Menschen zum Christengott ausdrücken
>   kann. Vor oder neben der religiösen Verwendung darf wohl ein Gebrauch
>   im Sinne von ‘sich auf einen Menschen verlassen, ihm vertrauen’ (vgl.
>   aengl. gelīefan ‘jmdm. vertrauen, sich auf jmdn. verlassen’, Beowulf)
>   angenommen werden. Aus ‘jmdm. vertrauen in bezug auf die Wahrheit
>   seiner Aussage’ entwickelt sich ‘etw. für wahr halten’, dann auch ‘für
>   möglich halten, vermuten, meinen’ (bereits ahd.). – Glaube m., auch
>   Glauben (seit dem 15. Jh. mit -n aus den flektierten Kasus),
>   ‘Vertrauen, Zuversicht, innere Gewißheit von Gott, religiöse
>   Überzeugung, Bekenntnis’, ahd. gilouba f. und giloubo m. (beide 8.
>   Jh.), mhd. g(e)loube f. m., asächs. gilōҍo m., mnd. g(e)lōve m., mnl.
>   ghelōve m. f. n., nl. geloof n., aengl. gelēafa m., engl. belief,
>   Abstraktbildungen zum Verb. Im Dt. gilt maskulines Genus seit spätmhd.
>   Zeit. gläubig Adj. ‘vertrauensvoll, an Gott, die Lehre der Kirche
>   glaubend, fromm’, ahd. giloubīg (9. Jh.), mhd. g(e)loubec.
>   Substantiviert ¹Gläubiger m. ‘Bekenner des Christentums, frommer
>   Mensch’, ahd. giloubīgo, mhd. g(e)loubige; allgemein (seit 18. Jh.)
>   ‘Anhänger einer Religion, einer Glaubenslehre’. ²Gläubiger m. ‘wer aus
>   einem Vertragsverhältnis von einem anderen eine Leistung, bes. Geld,
>   zu fordern hat, Geld-, Kreditgeber’, spätmhd. geloubiger (14. Jh.),
>   Übersetzung von lat. crēditor (und wohl auch von ital. creditore),
>   ebenfalls Substantivierung des Adjektivs gläubig, jedoch mit
>   festgewordener ehemaliger Flexionsendung -er (nach dem Muster der
>   Nomina agentis), semantisch anknüpfend an glauben im Sinne von ‘jmdm.
>   etw. anvertrauen, borgen’. glaubhaft Adj. ‘**vertrauenswürdig**,
>   glaubwürdig, **zuverlässig**, **überzeugend**’, ahd. giloubhaft ‘rechtgläubig’
>   (9. Jh.), mhd. geloubehaft ‘glaubend, gläubig, glaubwürdig’. glaublich
>   Adj., bis ins 18. Jh. auch gläublich, ‘überzeugend, verläßlich,
>   wahrhaftig’, ahd. giloublīh (um 800), mhd. geloublich. unglaublich
>   Adj. ‘unwahrscheinlich, unglaubhaft, ungeheuerlich, unfaßbar,
>   unerhört’, als Adverb (steigernd) ‘überaus, sehr’, ahd. ungiloublīh
>   (um 1000), mhd. ungelouplich, ungeloubelich ‘ungläubig, nicht zu
>   glauben’. glaubwürdig Adj. ‘glaubhaft’ (15. Jh.), anfänglich im
>   Bereich des Rechtswesens.

Comment: Die einseitigen Bezüge auf einen Christengott wirken arg überholt - was soll denn am Christengottglauben anders sein als an einem Judengott, einem Hindugott, einem Heidengott oder was das Herz sonst begehrt?

Answer (score 0):

*Glauben* drückt an sich keine Unsicherheit (auch keine Zweifel) aus, sondern nur, dass man *nicht weiß*.

> Ich habe der Polizei gesagt, dass ich den Mord nicht begangen habe und die glauben mir.

oder

> Ich glaube, das Universum ist unendlich.

in beiden Fällen kann man ziemlich sicher annehmen, dass der Sprecher davon überzeugt ist, oder zumindestens hofft, dass die Annahme zutrifft. Es ist auch schwierig bis unnmöglich, beide Annahmen (oder ihr Gegenteil) zu beweisen.

Es ist eins der Basisprinzipien von Religionen, dass sie auf dem *Glauben* basieren.

Könnte man

> Ich glaube, dass es einen Gott gibt

schlüssig wissenschaftlich beweisen, wäre es keine große Kunst, das zu glauben (und idiotisch, das Gegenteil anzunehmen).

Könnte man das Gegenteil beweisen, wäre es einigermaßen idiotisch, trotzdem daran zu glauben. Wäre das Eine oder das Andere schlüssig beweisbar, wäre in beiden Fällen die Religion dazu ziemlich witzlos.

Der "Witz" (also das kollektive Selbstverständnis der Gläubigen) bei (im Prinzip jeder, ich gehe mal vom Christentum aus) Religion ist ja eben, dass man nicht sicher wissen kann und trotzdem glaubt. Es ist eben diese Überbrückung der Unsicherheit, die (zumindestens die modernen) Religionen ausmacht.

Answer (score -1):

"Ich glaube, dass es morgen regnet" - dass drückt nicht meine Unsicherheit aus, den Unterschied zwischen 100 prozentiger Zuversicht und nur 80%, sondern meine Zuversicht, die 80% ist und nicht 0 Prozent.

Damit wird die gesamte Prämisse der Frage völlig unsinnig.

Comment: Ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt nicht so ganz, was du mir damit sagen möchtest. Die Prämisse ist, dass man "glauben" allgemein bei unsicheren Sachen benutzt ("Denkst du, dass es Aliens gibt?" -- "Ich glaube schon, aber ich weiß es nicht"). Zusätzlich nutzt man das Wort aber, wenn man von etwas wie Religion fest überzeugt ist ("Ich glaube, dass Gott existiert"). Wo ist die Prämisse jetzt falsch?

Comment: Du nahmst an, das "glauben" Unsicherheit ausdrückt. Das ist falsch. Auf einer Skala von 0 bis 100 (0 = völlig unsicher, 100 = völlig sicher) ist "Ich glaube, dass es morgen regnet" ziemlich weit oben. Nirgendwo in der Nähe von "Unsicherheit".

Comment: Im übrigen drückt "glauben" das Fehlen eines Beweises aus. Was im Alltagsleben den kleinen Unterschied zur völligen Sicherheit ausmacht, im religiösen Leben jedoch von ganz essentieller Wichtigkeit ist - das Fehlen eines Beweises ist kein Mangel, sondern gibt dem glauben gerade seine Wichtigkeit.